# How do I install Apache2 and PHP without the internet connection?

Tags: wifi, internet, php, apache-httpd

I do not have access to internet on my Pi. So I cannot install the above mentioned software using `sudo apt-get install apache2 php5` I have downloaded all the files form http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apache2/ and have run the command sudo dpkg -i *.deb but it did not install. Can any one help me do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, assuming that you've downloaded them onto your machine, and then have put them on your pi's SD card, you can install from local versions of packages, by [following the answer here.](https://superuser.com/questions/196864/how-to-install-local-deb-packages-with-apt-get/698249)

This can be summarised as using the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/filename.deb
```

You may find that those packages have some dependencies that you'll also need to install, which may get a bit time consuming.   Did you get an error message when you ran it with the wildcard?  My suggestion would be to double check the path name and use the full path to each individual file, rather than trying to batch install them using that wildcard.